# JQuery Autocomplete Custom Lookup Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to use jquery.autocomplete.js plugin for an input in my form. I want to search on the client side and can't use ajax. But I don't want some simple "Contains"-based search algorithm within an array. What I want to do is to write a custom search function in javascript to search and order the results. Is this even possible and how?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It surely is. You specify `source` to be a function which will answer a list of strings or alternatively `{label, value}` objects.

```
$('#myInput').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        var data = handleAutocomplete( term);  /* get answers from somewhere.. */
        response( data);
    }
});

function handleAutocomplete (term) {
    var options = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
    // use 'term' for custom filtering etc.
    return options;
}
```

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Great help my friend. But I think in the autocomplete(... you forgot {} for options argument. Thanks a lot.